# Which part of OpenGL ES does make my iPhone App bit slow?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, camera, glsl, mirror

I am currently developing my iPhone App with OpenGL ES. It is mirror app with brightness  and contrast. But the problem i am having now is it is bit slower(about 0.2s delay) when you use it. But the frame rate is about 60 seconds. So my quesion is which part of OpenGL takes time to process?

Comment: This is a very vague question... profile your code and see what takes a long time, then optimize that.

Comment: thanks. i am gonna use OpenGL ES Performance Detective. The method I should know earlier was already in the SDK.

Comment: It's probably not OpenGL-ES giving you the performance hit, but the upfront video processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is lag (not slowness). And it's not caused by OpenGL (at least not entirely). The latencies happen in the camera and the process of reading and decoding the camera pictures.

Some latency is unavoidable:

1. It takes a whole video frame for the camers to capture the image and to encode the image into digital data
2. It takes a whole display frame do draw the frame to the display.

So the shortest lag you can get are about 1s/30 + 1s/60 = 0.05s

Any latency above this is created due to processing overhead. And most likely I'd say yours comes from decoding the image and maybe buffer allocations in that process. However I'd need to see your sourcecode to tell for sure.